# css button on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

i wanted to make a log-in button with the `type="submit"` with an image that has an hover image too and :active image also,
well its work fine on **firefox** and chrome, but on **internet explorer** its just give the basic image and not giving the hover image and the active image.
and beside that, its make a dotted line on the button when you click on it.

**how its show on IE:**

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/72/ieproblem.jpg/

how its show on chrome and firefox:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/685/chromes.jpg/

```
.button
 {
    border:none;
    background: url(../img/login.jpg);
    width:41px;height:19px;
   }
    .button:hover 
        {
        background: url(../img/loginhover.jpg)  no-repeat top left;
        width: 41px;
        height: 19px;
        }

 .button:active {

 background: url(../img/loginactive.jpg);
   }
```

the button code on HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value=""/>
```

Comment: Please post your CSS code that you're using, I'd love to help you out if you do.

Comment: The 'dotted' line can be a very important accessibility feature. You should not worry about that if possible.

Comment: i updated the post, with the css code. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using earlier versions of IE, it has issues with :hover.

if you are using the ie7 >

you need to add href to your anchor,  :hover is not picked up by IE otherwise:

and to remove the outline you can try

```
a {
   outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: i have more objects with :hover in the css which work perfectly, this is the only problem. maybe because its a type="submit"?

Comment: @NullPointer Slightly confused. You're solution refers to the code as if it is an anchor tag but it is an input button. From the code that was posted, there doesn't appear to be an anchor tag unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @asafregev try something like `input[type="submit"]` to select the submit button

Comment: Got ya. That makes a little more sense. Thanks. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @War10ck dont apologies ... buddy its ok ... and i have no problem with it ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused by the `outline` property within IE.

Check out http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/ for some tips on how to remove it.

```
a {
   outline: 0;
}
```

Or apply the `outline` style to other elements.

Comment: OP should leave the outline if possible, as it is an important accessibility feature.

Comment: @KevinBoucher Yup I agree. However we all know what clients are like ;) Always wanting this that they shouldn't have :P

Comment: i tried this, its not changing it. actually this dotted outline appear when i load my page, and when i click on the button its looks like nothing happen. nothing change, no the image of the button. and either not the dotted outline